# Loading WikiEditor on dynamically created Textarea

Tags: javascript, editor, wiki, mediawiki-extensions

I want to load WikiEditor in a dynamically created textarea on a special page.

```
 var textbox = document.createElement('textarea');
 var textnode = document.createTextNode(text);
 textbox.appendChild(textnode);
 document.getElementById('new').appendChild(textbox);
 textbox.id  = 'wpTextBox1';
 textbox.name= 'wpTextBox1';
```

The text area is successfully created but I am not able to understand: which modules to load for loading WikiEditor?

This is what I have currently:
[image: Screenshot of Special:RCPatrol]

Comment: Are you actually talking of WikiEditor, or something else? https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WikiEditor

Comment: @Nemo  I  have a special Page on which I want to dynamically load wikieditor on a textbox when a user clicks on the edit button .

Comment: @Nemo you can see what I am trying to convey http://wikidifferences.com/index.php/Special:RCPatrol    On clicking edit it button I want to load wikieditor in place of textbox.